# Ploting point clouds using Matlab

Tags: matlab, kinect, matlab-cvst, point-clouds

I am using below code to plot the Kinect point clouds in Matlab:

```
showPointCloud(pcloud, 'VerticalAxis', 'y', 'VerticalAxisDir', 'Down');
xlabel('X (m)');
ylabel('Y (m)');
zlabel('Z (m)');
```

Which give me this plot : 
[image]

But I wish to plot it up to 1 m in Z value! How can I set it to display point clouds up to 1 m?

Comment: Check [`zlim`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zlim.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo, you should make it an answer.

Comment: @Dima Thanks. It was really easy, and the OP has already posted it as an answer, so he will be able to accept it after the appropriate time period (not sure how much time it is)

Comment: how u get your kinect data to matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@LuisMendo` responded in comments:

when i use `zlim` the plot has changed as below :

[image]

This is the edited code :

```
showPointCloud(pcloud, 'VerticalAxis', 'y', 'VerticalAxisDir', 'Down');
xlabel('X (m)');
ylabel('Y (m)');
zlabel('Z (m)');

zlim ([0,1])
```

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" this answer (click on the big tick mark in the upper left) when you can, so that the question doesn't appear as unanswered